# PIG - LOAD continue on error

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

New to pig.

I'm loading data into a relation like so:

```
raw_data = LOAD '$input_path/abc/def.*;
```

It works great, but if it can't find any files matching def.* the entire script fails.

Is here a way to continue with the rest of the script when there are no matches.  Just produce an empty set?

I tried to do:

```
raw_data = LOAD '$input_path/abc/def.* ONERROR Ignore();
```

But that doesn't parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom load UDF that returns either the file or an empty tuple.

http://wiki.apache.org/pig/UDFManual

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such feature, at least the one that I've heard of.
Also I would say that "producing an empty set" is "not running the script at all".

If you don't want to run a Pig script under some circumstances then I recommend using wrapper shell scripts or Pig embedding:
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/cont.html